# How to motify default Javascript function comment?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, monaco-editor

I have written an V8 engine extension which has a Javascript funtion named 'setInterval' just like the standard Javascript does!

Now I am using monaco-editor to edit my extended Javascript code. So, my question is, how to replace the default doxygen comment of 'setInterval' by what i did.

```js
/**
 * start the timer 
 * @param {function} callback
 * @param {number} interval   
 * @returns {number} timer id created
 */
function setInterval(callback, interval) {

}
```

Comment: Consider naming your own function something different so you don't run into name collisions.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I can not rename my function, because this will offer to end user.

Comment: Still, you should definitely not use the name of a system function, which is know for a specific functionality and behavior. Reusing its name is prone to all kind of confusion and errors. Instead give your new function a proper name which also describes it's functionality.